# How can I use pandas apply() to call a web service efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, web-services, apply

I need to populate a column in a dataframe based on the result of a web service which uses data from another column.  The Web Service I am using only allows for 3 concurrent requests at the time.  I was wondering if I can control that when using the pandas dataframe apply() method or if I should look for a different alternative (e.g. "walking / looping" through the dataframe records three at the time). Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Function to call a web service
# Return NonActive for non active and Active for active
def get_status(x):
    status_web_service = r'http://www.example.com/?id=' + x
    response = requests.get(status_web_service)
    return response.text()

# Main body starts here
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', 'Jane'], ['2', 'John']] , columns=['id', 'Name'])
df['Status'] = df['id'].apply(get_status)
```

My expected output (content of the dataframe) would be something like:

```
id, Name, Status
1, Jane, Active
2, John, NonActive
```

Any suggestion is welcome, either to work the issue this way or through a better alternative.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that .apply() resolves each row before going into the next, I do not think you will have problems with concurrent requests. However, you might need to consider putting in a small sleep timer (e.g. time.sleep()) within your apply function if the web services has a limit on request frequency.

Comment: Thank you @HaukenM, I was not sure if apply was concurrent (or actually simulating concurrency) or if would processed one row at the time.  This clarifies it.  Thanks very much for the answer.